# How to add a program to a group

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a program 'vboxmanage' that is owned by root and root ( means root user and root group I suppose ). My requirement is that the program vboxmanage should be accessible by another program 'minikube'. I was thinking about this solution that I should add minikube to root group and then it should be able to access vboxmanage. But minikube is not a user, so can anyone tell me about how to add minikube to root group.

Comment: What do you mean by "minikube is not a user"?  What about allowing minikube to run the command using `sudo`? Adding the user to the `root` group would not be a great idea.

Comment: minikube is not there in /etc/passwd file

Comment: Ah, I see now. So, what user does `minikube` run as?

Comment: I run minikube using sudo and then minikube internally calls vboxmanage and here i suppose that minikube doesnt call vboxmanage as sudo and that's why it throws error relating to vboxmanage cant create vm etc.

Comment: If you run the program using `sudo`, I'm assuming it runs as the root user?  Again, what user does `minikube` actually run as?

Comment: its sudo, that is the root user.

Comment: Ok, so it's running as root. This means that it will run `vboxmanage` as root as well. What is the actual and full error message that you get when it tries to run `vboxmanage`? You should add this to the question.

Comment: Also note that whatever user owns a command is irrelevant to what user is able to or should use a command. See e.g. `/bin/ls` for another example of a command that is likely owned by root. In this case, it's more interesting to see the actual error that you get and whether it's related to running as root or not, or whether it's something completely different that is happening.